# shell command to skip file in sequence

Tags: shell, sh

I run a C++ code for several data files in sequence using:

```
for i in $(seq 0 100); do ./f.out c2.$(($i*40+495)).bin `c2.avg.$(($i*40+495)).txt; done`
```

Now if some input files are missing, say c2.575.bin is missing then the command is not executed for the rest of the files. How could I modify the shell command to skip the input files those are missing and move to the next input file?

Thanks.

Comment: An error in one iteration of the loop should not prevent other iterations of the loop from continuing unless you have set the shell to exit on an error.

Comment: Also `{0..100}` is better than using `seq` when you can.

Comment: Thanks. Replacing seq by {0..100} works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the loop, test if file exists before calling a program operating on that file:

```
for i in $(seq 0 100); do
  INPUT=c2.$(($i*40+495)).bin
  test -e $INPUT && ./f.out $INPUT c2.avg.$(($i*40+495)).txt
done
```

This way the `./f.out ...` will be executed only for existing input files.

See [man test](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/test.1.html) for details.

BTW, the `&&` notation is a shorthand for if. See `help if` or `man sh`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `{0..100}` instead of `$(seq 0 100)` for better readability. You can put the following code in a script and execute the script. e.g., `runCode.bash`

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {0..100}
do
  # Assign a variable for the filenames
  ifn=c2.$(($i*40+495)).bin
  # -s option checks if the file exists and size greater than zero
  if [ -s "${ifn}" ]; then
     ./f.out "${ifn}" c2.avg.$(($i*40+495)).txt
  else
     echo "${ifn} No such file"
  fi
done
```

Change permission and execute the script.

```
chmod u+x runCode.bash`
./runCode.bash`
```

Comment: This is also great. Thank you.